# Counting Values from Different Pandas Dataframes with Certain Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, multiple-conditions

I have datasets similar to this:

`df1`

| company | date | act_call | act_visit | po |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-10-01 | Yes | No | No |
| B | 2022-10-01 | Yes | No | Yes |
| C | 2022-10-01 | No | No | No |
| B | 2022-10-02 | No | Yes | No |
| A | 2022-10-02 | No | Yes | No |

`df2`

| company | date | act_call | act_visit | po |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | 2022-11-01 | Yes | No | No |
| B | 2022-11-01 | Yes | No | Yes |
| C | 2022-11-01 | Yes | Yes | No |
| D | 2022-11-02 | No | Yes | No |
| A | 2022-11-02 | No | Yes | Yes |

I want to count the number of company where the `po` is 'No' in `df1` but also exists in `df2`.

I tried using this code:

`int_df = len(set(df2['company']).intersection(df1['po'].eq('no').groupby(df1['company'])))`

but it returns below error:

`unhashable type: 'Series'`

**My expected output:**

2, (A, C)

*notes: the (A, C) doesn't have to be printed since I actually only want the number of the company.

What would be the best code to my expected output? Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would filter first the companies based on `df2` with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), then aggregate with [`groupy.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) to identify the company with only "No", and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
(df1.loc[df1['company'].isin(df2['company']), 'po']
    .eq('No')
    .groupby(df1['company']).all()
    .sum()
)
```

Output: `2`

Comment: I get this error: `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input that triggers this error (as code if possible), your example in the question doesn't

Comment: I have multiple dataframes that I want to check the values counted. I use `merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])` to merge df1 and df2, then use the code above to check the number of the same values with the above condition for df3. so the overall code that gives error is: `(merged_df.loc[merged_df['company_name'].isin(df3['company_name']), 'po'].eq('no').groupby(merged_df['company_name']).all().sum())`

Comment: I see, add `ignore_index=True` as parameter to `concat`.